Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware())
I am following a YouTube Tutorial to build a next.js project with Clerk.
However, I keep getting these error messages on the terminal everytime the site is loaded:-
 Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()). Please ensure the following:
-  clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()) is used in your Next.js Middleware.
- Your Middleware matcher is configured to match this route or page.
- If you are using the src directory, make sure the Middleware file is inside of it.

For more details, see https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs

    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "4043468081"
 ⨯ Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()). Please ensure the following:
-  clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()) is used in your Next.js Middleware.
- Your Middleware matcher is configured to match this route or page.
- If you are using the src directory, make sure the Middleware file is inside of it.

For more details, see https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs

    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "3666937045"
 ⨯ Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()). Please ensure the following:
-  clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()) is used in your Next.js Middleware.
- Your Middleware matcher is configured to match this route or page.
- If you are using the src directory, make sure the Middleware file is inside of it.

For more details, see https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs

    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "4043468081"

Here is my middleware.ts :-
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware();

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};

Here's the file structure of the project:
file structure
Could anyone please help? Thanks!
I tried to move the middleware.ts to src file that I created for fixing this error, but no luck.

Make sure that the middleware.ts is either in the root of the project if you have no /src folder and if you do have /src put the middleware.ts file in there. You can also add debug:true to the Middleware to see if there is more info to help.
Do you know what route this is happening on?

To resolve this error, here's what worked for me:

First, I stopped the development server by pressing Control + C on macOS or CTRL + C on Windows.
Then, I ran the command npm run build to check for any build errors. Fortunately, there were none.
Next, I started the production server using npm start and observed that the error did not occur in the production environment.
Finally, I restarted the development server by running npm run dev, and the error no longer appeared in the terminal.

I'm not entirely sure what fixed the issue, but this process worked for me.
